# Wordpress - Multiple Post Queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to query posts for categories:

```
<?php query_posts("cat=8"); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
                 <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
             </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

It seems to work fine, until I did it a third time(three instances of the code above) on a single page. Now the page seems to load forever and it breaks as if it is compiling more then 1 page template. I should mention that all works fine unless I publish a post to the third category

Has anyone had a problem like this, or know why it happens?
Is this bad practise for querying posts?

Comment: If you need to run multiple loops on one page you should use get_posts instead of query_posts.  query_posts is meant for altering the main loop.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Secondary_Loops

Comment: I have tried this also, it still returns the same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WP_query instead so you can make use of the wp_reset_postdata which should clear up the issue.

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=8' );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
    <article>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </article>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought that would fix it too... but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Right now I currently have the third category empty, and it functions fine. The second I drop a post into that category is when the page starts breaking